# Need to pull records from previous full hour regardless of time the query runs

Tags: sql, oracle, hour

I want to pull records from the previous Full hour from when the query runs.

By this I mean regardless if it runs at 2:05 or 2:15 I will get records from 1:00:00 to 1:59:59.

Currently I get ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error even though there are correct amount of parenthesis as far as I can tell. What am I doing wrong?

```
WHERE ((SS.NSAMPLE < SS.LSL OR SS.NSAMPLE > SS.USL) OR SS.FAILED = 'Y')
AND SD.DIMENSION_ID = SS.DIMENSION_ID
AND SUBDATE(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H'), '%Y%m%d%H'), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) <= SS.SAMPLE_DATE AND SS.SAMPLE_DATE < STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H'), '%Y%m%d%H')
```

I also tried this and get the same missing right parenthesis error.

```
SUBDATE(SUBDATE(SUBDATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM NOW()) MICROSECOND),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NOW()) SECOND),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NOW()) MINUTE),
        INTERVAL 1 HOUR) <= SS.SAMPLE_DATE
    AND SS.SAMPLE_DATE < SUBDATE(SUBDATE(SUBDATE(NOW(),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM NOW()) MICROSECOND),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NOW()) SECOND),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NOW()) MINUTE)
```

Comment: tag your database as well

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean by database? I am using this query to build an alert in Delmia Works IQMS database.

Comment: SUBDATE, STR_TO_DATE, NOW etc. are MySQL functions, not Oracle RDBMS. You've tagged as Oracle and the error suggests that too (it's helpful to include the error code - are you getting ORA-00907?), so not sure why you're using MySQL syntax. Please edit your question to confirm the database and version, and the table structures, sample data, and expected results for that data.

Comment: Yes its ORA-00907 error. I am an absolute newb to SQL query. Just trying to adjust a current query that pulls the previous 60 minutes to report the previous full hour is all I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're using MySQL functions against an Oracle database. They are different database products, which both happen to be owned by Oracle Corp. (and have their documentation on docs.oracle.com), and the syntax varies. You might find the Oracle [SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Introduction-to-Oracle-SQL.html) helpful.

To get data from the preceding hour in Oracle you can do:

```
AND SS.SAMPLE_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'HH') - INTERVAL '1' HOUR
AND SS.SAMPLE_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'HH')
```

- `SYSDATE` gives you the system time, e.g. 2022-12-21 17:30:37
- `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'HH')` gives you the system time truncated to the hour, e.g. 2022-12-21 17:00:00
- `TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'HH') - INTERVAL '1' HOUR` gives you the system time truncated to the hour, with an hour subtracted, e.g. 2022-12-21 16:00:00

The two filter conditions then look for values greater than or equal to the previous hour, and less than (but not including) this hour, so effectively for that example system time:

```
AND SS.SAMPLE_DATE >= timestamp '2022-12-21 16:00:00'
AND SS.SAMPLE_DATE <  timestamp '2022-12-21 17:00:00'
```

which covers all of the possible times in that hour-long period.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DxXaYhiN)

---

The "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" error doesn't always mean you have the wrong number of parentheses. It means the parser got to a point where the next thing it expected to see was a right parenthesis, and it saw something else instead. It can have a variety of sometime non-obvious underlying problems.

In this case it's actually the interval syntax that's confusing it - if you change `INTERVAL 1 HOUR` to `INTERVAL '1' HOUR` to make it a valid Oracle interval literal then the error will change to "ORA-00904: "STR_TO_DATE": invalid identifier", which is easier to understand, as that's one of the MySQL functions that doesn't exist in Oracle.

Comment: That works great! Thanks a lot for the help. Now I also know that SQL works differently depending on the database and I will make sure to look for Oracle SQL queries specifically.

Comment: @RobertMalloy - glad it helped; I've just added a link to the Oracle docs, which includes all the valid functions etc.